# How to prevent SSH timeout of idle sessions?

Tags: ssh

I'm using iterm2 to SSH from a Mac to an RHEL server.  `ServerAliveInterval` is set to 60 in the client SSH config and `TCPKeepAlive` is set to 'yes' in the server sshd config.  However, idle sessions always timeout after some period (I have not timed it).  Running sessions, e.g. a long-running process or a `tail` will stay alive indefinitely.  Is there some way to keep idle sessions alive using some combination of server, client, and iterm2 settings that I have been unable to find?

Comment: Do you happen to have `TMOUT` set in your environment?

Comment: Oh, wow, good call.  It is set to 900, which matches the 15 minute timeout I am seeing.  Is that a per user (user I am ssh-ing to) setting?  And it looks like 0 is never?

Comment: Thanks @doneal24, between that and the config changes suggested below, things are behaving much better.  Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 2):

I am using `ServerAliveInterval` on a client side together with `ClientAliveInterval` on a server side for that purpose and I haven't seen drops (except the case of total loss of connectivity) in years.

I don't set `TCPKeepALive` but I believe it is on by default (but I doubt it is ever generated as my above settings are in a range which likely prevents it).

For the case when the connection drops/hangs I suggest using `tmux` or `screen` and run a program inside it. You will be able to resume the session on subsequent connection. This of course only works for command line / text applications, X forwarding will break.

EDIT:

I am using:

```
ClientAliveInterval 60
ClientAliveCountMax 5
```

and

```
ServerAliveInterval 30
ServerAliveCountMax 10
```

I probably should change the latter to match the former.

Comment: `ClientAliveInterval` is set to 300.   I think it is timing out longer than 5 minutes, but I will lower that to 60 to see if it helps.  Thanks for the suggestion.

I do use screen and/or tmux (can't decide which I prefer) for network drops, but my immediate problem is that I just hate having to restart idle sessions every time I go to do something.

Comment: I added both your changes and set TMOUT to 0 as suggested by @doneal24 and it has not timed me out after 30+ minutes.  Thanks!